# Will the center have enough support for my custom desk/table?

Tags: furniture, design, tabletop, table-making

I'm trying to build my first large desk for my computer setup. My plan is to set a 74" × 42" laminate counter top on top of four Alex drawers and I am concerned about the center of the table sagging or breaking without an apron for support. I drew a top down view of the table quickly and was wondering what I should add for support to strengthen the center if needed.
[The countertop](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/ekbacken-countertop-for-kitchen-island-matte-anthracite-laminate-90499108/),
[The drawers](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/alex-drawer-unit-black-brown-60473548/), [The design](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijsBeABO05cEYm2tXSNn-OgynCjNaqpj/view?usp=drivesdk)
Most of the weight will be located near the top of the table with three monitors. Other than that I'm planning on having just a keyboard, mouse, and maybe some light nick-knacks scattered throughout.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. It's not clear from the text, what do the blue lines represent in the diagram? I don't think you'll have a problem either way, but it may be worth clarifying that.

Comment: The blue lines represent the gap between the Alex drawers. I only made those to see what space I would have under the desk.

Comment: Ah good, just had to check whether they were some sort of apron pieces.

Comment: Guessing you mean “*without* an apron for support…”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laminate countertop material is very stiff. 46" is just over 1m and such spans are normal in many kitchen designs. After 1 year of use I expect laminate will deflect, but you will not notice (maybe 1-2mm).

If deflection can be seen after many months easy to install central leg same height as Alex drawers for support.

Answer (score 0):

That counter top is 1 1/8" thick so it should be fine across that span.

If it deflects more than desired, you could add angle irons between the front and/or rear sets of the red boxes (green lines in the drawing) to stiffen it up a bit.

[image: Reinforcements added to orig. drawing]

You might want to add this reinforcement anyhow if there's a chance that someone will sit on the desk. Again though, I think the manufactured thickness is adequate for this case, but I'm not very familiar with the quality of Ikea components.